# Date gets changed when saved to DB

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql

I'm using PostgreSQL and I have a column named `reservation_date` which type is `date`.

Also, I set my timezone to Tokyo in `application.rb`

I try to save it to the DB like below:

```
reservation = Reservation.first
reservation.reservation_date = Time.zone.today
=> Sat, 18 Nov 2017
reservation.save
```

When I check the `reservation_date` again, it shows "Mon, 20 Nov 2017"
I really don't understand why...

Comment: I'm guessing that the reservation was not saved, and it kept the old `reservation_date`, can you confirm that you save it successfully?

Comment: As far as I know, postgres doesn't differentiate time zones, so if you've configured it in your app it won't matter to the db. Maybe try saving the time as UTC, I think it should convert to local time when read back, or you may need to convert it, but I believe storing it as UTC rather than local time should work.

Comment: Well...I wanted to dig a hole and crawl into it.
I forgot I have a before_save to skip some specified date.